# Wildfly enable datasource statistics returns "JBAS014792: Unknown attribute statistics-enabled"

Tags: java, mysql, wildfly

When I try to enable the statistic for a mysql datasource in wildfly it throws me the following error:

```
Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "result" => {"step-1" => {
        "outcome" => "failed",
        "failure-description" => "JBAS014792: Unknown attribute statistics-enabled",
        "rolled-back" => true
    }},
    "failure-description" => {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => "JBAS014792: Unknown attribute statistics-enabled"}},
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

I use a normal mysql datasource which works without troubles. What can be wrong here?

Environment:

- java: 1.8.0_25
- Wildfly 8.2.0.Final
- mysql: mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have attribute **"statistics-enabled = true"** in **stanalone.xml** file under path **JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/stanalone.xml** for every datasource you are using.

To do that first you need to stop the JBoss server , modify the standalone.xml and then start the server.